# USB External Hard Drive

Tags: usb, external-hdd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)

I want to put a bootable Ubuntu in my USB External Hard Drive. But, I want to keep storing my files on it and the Ubuntu should save my settings there too (persistent). It sounds like a "Persistent live USB", but with these differences that I said before.

I've tried "[Create a USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)", but the Ubuntu wasn't saving my settings and files (and yes, I've created it with 4gb persistent file size). Actually I think what I want is not a "live USB".

Do you guys know how to install Ubuntu on a External HD and keeping storing things? I use Windows.

Comment: As I said, I'm using Windows... And I don't want to install on a Virtual Machine, as I said, I want a bootable Ubuntu.

Comment: You will have to boot from a Live DVD/USB (like the one you have made already) and start the installation from there. There is no way to do it from within Windows. Just don't install Ubuntu and its **bootloader, called GRUB** in the internal hard drive by mistake. :)

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate.  He wants to know how to use a bootable external hard drive for storage.